# What is the difference between the words negative and negatory?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, differences, synonyms

What is the difference between the words negative and negatory? I looked up the definitions [here](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/negatory) and they are pretty much [the same](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/negative?s=t).

Comment: Negatory is either a joke word, making fun of official jargon, or a genuine local variant of _negative_. It is not an official word of English; like _ain't, hafta, wanna,_ and _shee-it_, it's considered "dialect".

Comment: @JohnLawler in that sense couldn't any sound be claimed to be a "local variant" and it would never be possible to conclude there is no such word.

Comment: That's correct. But if it's recognized by speakers as a joke, it's still a joke.

Comment: @JohnLawler the "official words of English" are *ex* what *officio*? Whose publications should I consult? The Académie anglaise?

Comment: [The Academy](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/academy.html) rarely issues official bulletins. If you were to look in a good dictionary, you would find most of the official words and some of the unofficial words, but those would be marked _dial._ or some such.

Comment: For use of "negatory" in popular culture also see the Johnny Cash hit "One Piece at a Time", where the word is used in a simulated CB radio conversation.

Comment: I had the impression that the military use "negatory" since it is less likely to be misunderstood in bad conditions:  very noisy situations, or over a poor radio connection.

Answer (score 12):

***Early recorded use of 'negatory'***

One of the earliest instances of *negatory* that a Google Books search finds is in Elisha Coles, [*An English Dictionary, Explaining the Difficult Terms that are used in Divinity, Husbandry, Physick, Philosophy, Law, Navigation, Mathematicks, and other Arts and Sciences*](https://books.google.com/books?id=O4wNAAAAQAAJ&pg=PT220&dq=%22negatory%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj3jYvxlKjKAhWDJZQKHVICDOMQ6AEIKDAC#v=onepage&q=%22negatory%22&f=false) (1717), which provides the following simple definition:

> **Negatory**, *belonging to Denial*.

This entry follows two related terms:

> Negation, *a denying*.
>
> Negative, *belonging thereto, also that Manner of Expression*.

Clearly *negatory* and *negative* had very similar meanings at that time, though *negative* was (and remains) by far the more common term of the two.

Examples of *negatory* in the wild include this one in a legal decision, dated January 21, 1702, in [*The Decisions of the Lords of Council and Session, From June 6th, 1678, to July 30th, 1712*](https://books.google.com/books?id=nuPlAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA140&dq=%22negatory%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjp7prcyKjKAhUL0WMKHX5eBMs4HhDoAQghMAE#v=onepage&q=%22negatory%22&f=false) (1761):

> David Grant wright against Daniel Simpson writer to the signet. Each of them having a tenement at the Netherbow, Daniel claimed a passage or entry through David's land to his own, and stopped a fyre [?] for carrying off the water : whereupon David raises a reduction, and a **negatory** action of declaratory of his immunity and freedom from any such servitudes  ; and that the close is his own, and the little shop therein, and so cannot be  made a common entry by Daniel, &c.

Another early instance of *negatory* used in a legal context occurs in William Strahan's 1722 translation of Jean Domat, [*The Civil Law in Its Natural Order*](https://books.google.com/books?id=dvQ1AQAAMAAJ&pg=RA1-PA38&dq=%22negatory%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjp7prcyKjKAhUL0WMKHX5eBMs4HhDoAQgbMAA#v=onepage&q=%22negatory%22&f=false), Supplement to Book IV Of the Publick Law, Title I, "Of the Several Sorts of Judicial Demands and Actions," VI:

> When a Real Action is commenced by the Owner of a House or Lands, claiming a Service due from the House or Lands of another Person, that Action is called a *Confessory* Action. And the Name of ***Negatory*** Action is given to that which is brought by a Person, who insists that his House or Lands are not charged with the Service which is claimed to be due from them.

This definition seems well suited to the facts of the 1702 Grant v. Simpson dispute quoted above, where *negatory* appears.

We also have this nonlegal instance from "[Bavius *versus* Prompter](https://books.google.com/books?id=ZXZIAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA140&dq=%22negatory%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjAvPSiyKjKAhVY4mMKHW_yD1A4FBDoAQgnMAI#v=onepage&q=%22negatory%22&f=false)" in *The Gentleman's Magazine* (March 1736, quoted from *The Grubstreet Journal*, number 324):

> [B]ut now he has chang'd the Dispute to Whether these *Ifs* are any Denials at all ; and to prove that they are not, quotes *Philip*. iv. 8. *If there be any Virtue*, and if, &c, adds it may be as well asserted that these *Ifs* are implicit Denials of what is contained in that Verse—But any one who compares the *Prayer* with this Place of Scripture may see the contrary : The Word *If* is there used in an affirmatory Sense, but in several other Places in a ***negatory*** one, particularly *Psalm* cxxx, 30.

And from Benjamin Martin, [*Bibliotheca Technologica; or, a Philological Library of Literary Arts and Sciences*](https://books.google.com/books?id=9g5gAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA156&dq=%22negatory%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi2sZailajKAhXCoJQKHZdHBNk4ChDoAQgmMAI#v=onepage&q=%22negatory%22&f=false) (1740):

> TERMS are either *Positive* or *Negative*. *Positive Words* have an *affirmative Sense*, and signify some *Positive Idea* ; as *Art*, *Life*, *Sense*, *Motion*, &c. But *negative Terms* exhibit *negative Ideas*, or have a ***negatory** Sense* express'd by some *Particle* or *Preposition* of *Denying* join'd to them ; as *Artless*, *Lifeless*, *Senseless*, *Nonsense*, &c. ... But in many Cases *Positive Words* have *Negative Significations*, and the *contrary*, which is a great *Imperfection* and *Unhappiness* in Language.

This last example is particularly interesting because the author frequently uses the word negative in the same discussion and seems to introduce the term *negatory* to indicate a shade of difference, as if *negative* meant "negative" in the modern sense, while *negatory* meant something like "negating."

Johnson's *Dictionary of the English Language* (1756) omits *negatory*. Nevertheless, the term continues to appear (though never commonly) in serious works over the ensuing decades. For example, we have instances from law such as George Bowyer, [*Commentaries on the Modern Civil Law*](https://books.google.com/books?id=grzGNOlPso4C&pg=PA287&dq=%22negatory+action%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiVs8GSv6jKAhVBz2MKHZNqBrU4ChDoAQggMAE#v=onepage&q=%22negatory%20action%22&f=false) (1848):

> Thus a **negatory** action contains an assertion; and the right of servitude in the defendant being disproved, the right becomes established as part of the dominion or ownership of the proprietor, the residue of which was not in dispute.

And from "[Notice of Caldwell's Nicomachean Ethics](https://books.google.com/books?id=uNOLTFNl2_IC&pg=PA278&dq=%22negatory+adjective%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwji9NPlv6jKAhUBz2MKHeZNBAcQ6AEIHTAA#v=onepage&q=%22negatory%20adjective%22&f=false)," in *The Classical Journal* (December 1828):

> This shorter form of the ***negatory*** adjective is (it should be observed) quite agreeable to analogy: thus we have λóγος, λóγιμος, αλογος, not αλóγιμος ; μóρος, μóριμος, αμóρος not αμóριμος, &c.

And from history in Thomas Carlyle, [*The French Revolution: A History*](https://books.google.com/books?id=vsgNAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA24&dq=%22negatory+incoherences%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi2yf-IwqjKAhVY-2MKHXAtCqUQ6AEIRzAH#v=onepage&q=%22negatory%20incoherences%22&f=false), volume 3, *The Guillotine* (1837), writing about Caron de Beaumarchais, the author of *Figaro*:

> "At midnight" (it was but the 12th of August yet), "the servant in his shirt," with wide-staring eyes, enters your room: — Monsieur, rise; all the people are come to seek you; they are knocking, like to break-in the door! "And they were in fact knocking in a terrible manner (*d'une façon terrible*). I fling on my coat, forgetting even the waistcoat, nothing on my feet but slippers; and say to him" —  And *he*, alas, answers mere **negatory** incoherences, panic interjections.

And from logic in Augustus De Morgan, [*Formal Logic: or, The Calculus of Inference, Necessary and Probable*](https://books.google.com/books?id=mLljAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA93&dq=%22negatory+complex%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjIuea9wqjKAhUT-mMKHciyBEwQ6AEIIzAB#v=onepage&q=%22negatory%20complex%22&f=false) (1847), who describes a class of "negatory conclusions" that he defines in contradistinction to "affirmatory conclusions." He later remarks:

> Our conclusion is that no **negatory** complex syllogism is of any more logical effect than the strengthened particular derived from it. Thus we may say that, so far as the extent and character of the inference is concerned, the former is the latter.

Between 1850 and about 1975, many occurrences of *negatory* in Google Books search results involve law or logic (or both), though authors specializing in other areas such as history, psychology, and philosophy use it, too.

---

***"Negatory" after the coming of 'Convoy'***

The year of change for *negatory* was 1975, when the citizen's band radio fad blossomed in the United States, and C.W. McCall released his hugely popular recording "[Convoy](https://soundcloud.com/hamfan55/cw-mccall-convoy-original-version)," which uses (among other bits of contemporaneous CB radio slang) the word *negatory* in the sense of "no":

> Ah, you wanna give me a 10-9 on that, Pig Pen? **Negatory**, Pig Pen; you're still too close. Yeah, them hogs is startin' to close up my sinuses. Mercy sakes, you better back off another ten [miles].

If some people now view *negatory* as being strictly or primarily a joke word, CB radio slang may well be to blame. The humor (I suspect) derives from the perceived intellectual overreach of typical users of the term, since CB radio enthusiasts as a group are not widely viewed as being especially well educated. A similar instance of overreach is reported in the U.S. Supreme Court case, [*Brandenburg v. Ohio*](https://supreme.justia.com/cases/federal/us/395/444/case.html) (1969), where a Ku Klux Klan spokesperson is recorded on film giving a speech that, among other things, uses the novel terms *revengent* and *revengeance*:

> The Klan has more members in the State of Ohio than does any other organization. We're not a **revengent** organization, but if our President, our Congress, our Supreme Court, continues to suppress the white, Caucasian race, it's possible that there might have to be some **revengeance** taken. [395 U.S. 446]

As I recall, the Klansman's neologisms were a source of considerable amusement in the Constitutional Law class where I heard the case discussed.

Whatever the general perception of *negatory* may be, serious writers continue to use it completely seriously, as in Nicholas Tavuchis, [*Mea Culpa: A Sociology of Apology and Reconciliation*](https://books.google.com/books?id=FdVyGZzMDxEC&pg=PA68&dq=%22negatory+stance%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjHotihxqjKAhUP3mMKHTRrDhIQ6AEIJjAA#v=onepage&q=%22negatory%20stance%22&f=false) (1991):

> The ultimate **negatory** stance in a culture that does accord a place for apology would be the categorical denial of any obligation to respond to the call or, for that matter, even to give an account for an offense.

And Steven M. Cerutti, [*The Word of the Day: The Unlikely Evolution of Common English*](https://books.google.com/books?id=NWp_eZkWpL4C&pg=PA17&dq=%22negatory+prefix%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwin-92wxqjKAhVKx2MKHVb8C2UQ6AEIHTAA#v=onepage&q=%22negatory%20prefix%22&f=false) (2005):

> Ancient Greek has only one **negatory** prefix, the single letter alpha (α).

As for how *negatory* and *negative* differ in non-CB-radio-derived usage, *negatory* clearly works in far fewer contexts than *negative* does, because it has far fewer meanings—essentially, "denying or negating"—whereas *negative* applies as well to such areas as electromagnetic polarity and a cynical or pessimistic attitude. Still, within the narrower confines of "denying or negating," the terms are very similar. Just be aware that some readers or listeners are likely to reflexively think "Ten-four, good buddy" whenever they encounter the word *negatory*.

I should also point out that, despite its regular (though infrequent) use in certain areas of English for more than 300 years, *negatory* is not accorded an entry in *Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary* (2003) or its predecessors, suggesting that the people at Merriam-Webster have never regarded it as an everyday English word in good standing.